# How can I get the address of a char&?

Tags: c++

This code compiles but doesn't generate the results I'd expect:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char h = 'h';
    char& href = h;

    std::cout << &href << std::endl;

    int x = 1;
    int& xref = x;

    std::cout << &xref << std::endl;
}
```

The result is something like:

```
h
0x22fe38
```

How do I retrieve the address of the `char` my `char&` is aliasing?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I retrieve the address of the char my char& is aliasing?

The expression is `&href`.

The problem you are seeing is due to the fact that the type of `&href` is `char*`. Hence,

```
std::cout << &href << std::endl
```

tries to print a null terminated string. You can use

```
std::cout << (void*)&href << std::endl
```

to print the address.

Answer (score 3):

Simply cast it to `void*`:

```
std::cout << (void*)&href << std::endl;
```

You are printing the original character because `std::ostream`'s have a function that looks similar to this:

```
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, char const* val);
```

When you ask for the address of a character, you get a `char*`; as with any other type, the addressof `&` operator returns a pointer to the type. Since `char*` converts to `char const*`, the previously mentioned function is called, as if it were a null terminated string.